# Can't loop through JSON Object

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating a JS object, then stringifying it and trying to loop through the key-value pairs, but it is giving weird results. Please help.

```
var gv_array = {};
var gv_cookie_name = "_gv";
var gv_cookie_expiry = 1;
var $inv = jQuery.noConflict(); 

$inv('.product-image').bind('inview', function(event, isInView) {
   if (isInView) {
    var a = $inv(this).data('productid');       
    if(jQuery.inArray(a,gv_array) === -1){
        gv_array[a]=0;
    } 

    // Converting the array into JSON to save it to cookie

        var json_gv_arr = JSON.stringify(gv_array); 
        setCookie(gv_cookie_name,json_gv_arr,gv_cookie_expiry);

  }
});

$inv(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval('sendGV()',3000);
});

function sendGV(){
  var gv_cookie_val = getCookie(gv_cookie_name);
    gv_cookie_val = JSON.parse(gv_cookie_val);
   var gv_cookie_array = new Array();
      $inv.each( gv_cookie_val, function( key, value ) {
        if(value == 0){
               gv_cookie_array.push(key);
            }
     });
   alert(gv_cookie_array);
 }
```

The JS Object looks like this when i try to alert it.

```
 {"2234":0,"4563":0,"4555":0}
```

I need to send ids from the object whose value is 0 to insert into database and just after a receive the success msg from AJAX, i need to change the status of the ids in the object to 1.

**UPDATE**: Even after parsing the JSON string, it doesnt do anything.

Comment: you read the value from the cookie, but you don't do anything with it...

Comment: where are you getting the obj variable for use in your $.each function?

Comment: @MuppetGrinder That was a typo, i edited the question.

Comment: @doldt That is what i am doing, i am trying to loop through the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

try as like following:

```
var data = {"2234":0,"4563":0,"4555":0};

$.each(data,function(key,value){
    console.log(key+":"+value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure javacript:

```
data = {"2234":0,"4563":0,"4555":0};
keys = Object.keys(data);   // ["2234", "4563", "4555"]

for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  console.log(data[keys[i]]);   // 0, 0, 0
}
```

and for set the values:

```
for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  data[keys[i]] = 1
}

console.log(data); // Object { 2234=1,  4563=1,  4555=1}
```